# full width navigation with dynamic width to each item and equal to 100%

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'd like to have a full width navigation with 6 menu item, but each item have different length of words and those 6 items must have dynamic percentage width based on the length of words and they are equal to 100%.

Hope the image below will make it easier to understand:

[image]

Is it possible with css only? I've tried this for days but haven't found any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with flex personally

```css
.flex{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap
}

.logo{
  width:15%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  background:red;
}

.nav{
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 0 5%;
  width:80%;
}

.nav li{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:auto;
}

.nav li:first-child{
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex menu-container">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <ul class="nav flex">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Custom-made product &amp; private label</li>
    <li>Packaging</li>
    <li>Facility</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Social</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### CSS-Tables

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-row;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Custom Made Product & Private Label</li>
    <li>Packaging</li>
    <li>Facility</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Insta WA</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible only with CSS. Please check the codepen that I created for demo purpose you can have more styling and other things

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXrvrZ

```
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Custom Made Product & Private Label</li>
        <li>Packaging</li>
        <li>Facility</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Insta WA</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    *,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

    ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    }

    .menu {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Also check the guide for using CSS grid

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: That was just an example and not complete solution also I have provided link to CSS grid, hope OP also understand that I will not write complete code for him. Please don't mark negative if you are not OP